# Prevent submission form Data when enter on search

Tags: vue.js

I have form.inside this form component I have a search box.i created two methods one is for search other one is for submit data. every time I enter on search both methods are fires.

I used this `@submit.prevent="saveFormData"` for entire form and `v-on:submit.prevent keyup.enter ="searchCustomerRecord"` for search record
then the `searchCustomerRecords` not working at all

```
<form class="mx-auto w-full max-w-lg" @submit.prevent="saveFormData">
  ....
  <div class="sm:text-left my-2 md:text-right">
   <input type="search" class="w-full bg-purple-white"placeholder="Search Here..." 
   name="search" v-model="searchInput" v-on:keyup.enter ="searchCustomerRecord">
  </div> 
  .....

   <div class="flex-auto text-center px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
     <button type="submit" class="m-2 py-2 hover:bg-green-dark ">Save</button>
     <button class="m-2 py-2  hover:bg-red">Clear</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just catch the event earlier inside input and stop its propagation, like:

`<input type="search" @keydown.enter.prevent.stop="searchCustomerRecord" />`